# Can "for themselves" mean "for their own benefit" in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

> South-western Finland had begun its economic integration with central
> Sweden in the Viking era, which was a contributory factor in the
> spread of Christian customs and beliefs to Finland, since for
> diplomatic reasons the Swedish Viking chieftains were consenting to
> baptism **for themselves**, and did not prevent individual missionaries
> trying their luck in Finland.
>
> - A history of Finland by Henrik Meinander

The phrase "for themselves" (bold is mine) can mean two things in my view:

1. They themselves as an individual person consented to baptism.
2. They consented to baptism for their tribes for **their own benefit**.
   Which one is correct?

Comment: I read it as "were consenting to be baptized themselves". Together with the chieftains allowing (Christian) missionaries into Finland, this explains the "spread of Christian customs and beliefs".

Comment: There's no concept of ***for** [their personal benefit]* in the exact highlighted words. You should understand preposition ***for*** here as precisely equivalent to and interchangeable with *baptism **of** themselves* (their own baptism, which they agreed / consented to do / have done ***for diplomatic reasons***).